# Entire function mapping infinite strip to itself is a translation

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I ran into this while studying for my qual.

> Suppose $S=\{z:-\pi/2<\Im\{z\}<\pi/2\}$ and there is an entire function $g$ with $g(S)\subseteq (S)$. If $g(-1)=0$ and $g(0)=1$ prove that $g(z)=z+1$.

I tried to use Schwarz's lemma but to get from disc to strip or vice-versa the conformal maps involve logs and exps and things get ugly with estimates. Another approach would be to show that $g$ is an analytic automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ in which case we'd also be done; but, I am not sure how to get there without any injectivity assumptions on $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the conformal map $\varphi $ from the unit disc, $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1\}$, to the strip, $S=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |\text{Im } z|<\frac{\pi}{2}\}$, i.e. $\varphi:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow S$ given by
\begin{align}
\varphi(z) = \text{Log}\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)
\end{align}
and the translation map $\tau_{-1}:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by
\begin{align}
\tau_{-1}(z) = z-1.
\end{align}
Then we see that
\begin{align}
h:= \varphi^{-1}\circ\tau_{-1}\circ g\circ\varphi: \mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{D}
\end{align}
and $h(0) = (\varphi^{-1}\circ\tau_{-1}\circ g)(0) = \varphi^{-1}(0) = 0$. Moreover, we also see that
\begin{align}
h\left(\frac{1-e}{1+e}\right) = \frac{1-e}{1+e}
\end{align}
then by Schwarz's lemma we have that $h(z) = z$. In particular, it follows
\begin{align}
z = (\varphi^{-1}\circ\tau_{-1}\circ g\circ\varphi)(z) \ \ \ \implies \ \ \ (\tau_{-1}\circ g)(w) = w \ \ \ \implies \ \ \ g(w) = w+1
\end{align}
where $w = \varphi(z)$.